# How to activate the cloud function after a successful dataflow job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The code for my Apache Beam pipeline is below. My cloud function (Topic- name: projects/wisdomcircle-350611/topics/uat-timestamp-job-trigger) must only be activated when the dataflow task below is successful.

```
def run_pipeline(jdbc_url, username, password, wisgen_table):

options = PipelineOptions()
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
 
last_sync_data = (
 p | "Read last sync data" >> ReadFromBigQuery(
                query='SELECT MAX(time) as last_sync FROM '
                '[wisdomcircle-350611:custom_test_data.last_sync]')
 | "Extract last sync time" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: elem['last_sync'])
 )

wisgen_data = p | "wisgen job" >> ReadFromJdbc (
jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
username=username,
password=password,
driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
query="""SELECT users.id AS user_id, where to_char(users.updated_at,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= '{last_sync_data}' """,
table_name="users"
)

wisgen_data | "Convert TableRow to dict(wisgen data)" >> beam.Map(
lambda row: row._asdict()
) | "Write to BigQuery in wisgen data table" >> WriteToBigQuery(
wisgen_table,
write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
schema='user_id:INTEGER,full_name:STRING)

if __name__ == '__main__':
run_pipeline(
        jdbc_url='xxxx',
        username='xxxx',
        password='xxxx',
        wisgen_table='wisdomcircle-350611:uat_custom_dataset.wisgen_data_table',
    )
```

Comment: Did you have a look to eventarc?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  what event type and event provider I need choose so that cloud function will triggered just after my dataflow job is finished ?

Comment: Hmmm, i didn't know that Dataflow wasn't handled by Eventarc!! One of rare service not managed by it. You could use Cloud Workflow. The workflow runs the dataflow and when it's done, it continues to the next step and invoke the Cloud Functions. One constraint: max 30 minutes for Dataflow job. https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/dataflow/v1b3/projects.jobs/create